# Do JPA entities and DTOs belong to Service or Spring Repository layer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, service-layer

I want to write a JPA application, but I have problems understanding the repository and service concepts:

Consider we have 3 entities:
A, B and C.

Entity A needs to have B and C set: A.setB(B), A.setC(C) before it is saved.

Also for read, I want to return only DTOs since they will free me from [LazyInitializationException](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/), [Open Session In View Anti-Pattern](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/), etc, and for modifying data I will use entities ( these guidelines are also described in this book [High-Performance Java Persistence](https://vladmihalcea.com/books/high-performance-java-persistence/)).

First of all, the user will make a HTTP POST with some data which will be converted into ABCGuiObject. The REST controller will call serviceA.save(ABCGuiObject).

**Persist options:**

*Option #1*
- The service will create 3 objects A, B ,C and pass them to repositoryA.save(A,B,C). The repositoryA will do inside a.setB and a.setC.

*Option #2*
- The service will create 3 objects A, B ,C, do a.setB and a.setC and call repositoryA.save(A).

**DTO retrieval**

I would like to write a JPQL query to get some DTO. I do not want to convert entities to DTO, but retrieve them directly with JPQL.

*Option #1*
- repositoryA will return directly a DTO.

*Option #2*
- the service will pass a JPQL query to the repositoryA, which will have a general query method which returns a DTO.

What approaches do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Write data

The Service layer should construct the graph of entities `A`, `B` and `C` and connect them accordingly (`a.setB` and `a.setC`) and pass `A`, `B` and `C` to the Repository. If you have one-to-many associations, you can [cascade](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) [entity state transitions](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/).

### Read data

If you want to return DTOs, you are better off fetching DTOs directly from JPA and Hibernate. So, you have two options:

- you can use [JPQL Constructor Expressions](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
- you can use Hibernate-specific [`ResultTransformer`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-resulttransformer/)

Comment: Vlad but do I need to create one repository per entity class? What I understand from you is that the service will build the 3 entity classes from ABCGuiObject and then call repositoryA.save(a), repositoryB.save(b) and respoitoryC.save(c), either in the correct order or will use cascade. Is this correct? Also, for the DTO, some say it is not ok to return a DTO from repository, maybe because you will forward the DTO to the service and then REST. What do you think about this?

Comment: Spring Data requires you to create one Repository for each Entity type. As for the DTOs, of course, you need to return them from the Repository. Otherwise, you'll select entities and then turn them to DTOs. But why select multiple columns in order to fetch an entity when you only need a DTO projection?

Comment: But what about the service layer? Should I do a service per entity class or a general service that has relevant business methods and those call repositories as appropriate?

Comment: In my opinion, the Service Layer related to the business logic, not to the way you split your entities. But then, this is more like a matter of preference, and it's a subjective matter.

Comment: @Vlad I'm glad I found this answer. As you mentioned that Repositories can return DTO for retrieval. Should I create another (similar) dto for service layer , map repo dto to service dto and return it or should I return the dto from repo. If the DTO from repo leaves service and I call my service from a controller, would't I directly access my repo layer objects? For .e.g imports from repo layer in controler? Isn't that tight coupling?

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective thing but I'll share my opinion.
For Persist Options, I recommend Option #2. The repository ideally should just do "repository" duties, the service or if too complex you can delegate to a factory to build the A entity.

For the DTO retrieval, I would issue queries to retrieve the entities(so the repository would always return entities), and transform them to DTO. Someone may need the same repository feature and they can choose to transform to DTO, instead of writing another JPQL with DTO query.

Comment: But why return entities and then convert them to DTO when it is way more efficient to construct DTOs through JPQL? You know that data to select, and the joins get filtered at the database level, not in memory by Hibernate.

Comment: Entities are also POJOs and can be used in UI layer. No need to map them into DTO and back to entities when saving. Lazy collections can be fetched using `.size()` when transaction is still active, for example inside EJB method.

Comment: @user3030447 The "memory footprint" argument does not stand most of the times these days. Most of the times, you load a handful of entities  and transforming them to DTOs is practically not a problem.
Even in reporting, you should never load more than a few thousand records. 
Mapping to DTOs gives you more flexibility as UI often does not "match" the entity structure. You you can use the entities without DTO in simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

Persist option 2.

DTO objects are usually loading lazy fields. This can harm performance if you don't write separate query/mapping for different use cases. DO NOT USE DTO, instead initialize lazy fields per use case to avoid LazyIntializationException. Also it will save you lot work with mapping from and into entity for saving.

Comment: DTO will not load lazy fields. Think that I will write manual join in JPQL, and the filtering will be done at database level, so only the relevant information will be there. I will not use join fetch or fetch the entities and then convert them to DTO.

Comment: Yes, it depends how you are mapping entities into DTOs. Using mapping framework like Dozer collection will be loaded alwyas. This is not optimal regarding performance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the persisting, I'd go with option 2 but not for all service related actions. If you have simple actions like e.g. addComment, enable/disable then it might be better to only pass ids and let the service get it's hands on the entity itself.

For DTOs I suggest you give Blaze-Persistence Entity Views a look to see how easy the DTO pattern can be implemented. Here is a nice [article](https://blazebit.com/blog/2016/getting-started-with-blaze-persistence-entity-views.html) about getting started with it.